# Add custom settings bundle to jailbroken iOS settings.app?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, settings.bundle

I was looking into making a custom toggle switch option in the iOS settings.app menu to turn a home cooked function on and off. I was wondering if it's possible to do such a thing. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but it works a little differently for jailbreak apps, installed in `/Applications`, than it does for normal App Store apps.

[Take a look at this documentation here.](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader)  I haven't used it in a while, so if there are things that are out of date, post a comment here, and I'll try to update my answer with code, etc., from one of my working jailbreak apps that does this.

Note that if you want the Settings switch to *execute your custom code*, rather than just *storing* a preference value, you'll need to use the **PreferenceBundle Approach** described in the link above.

You'll also need to make sure the phone has `PreferenceLoader`, by Dustin Howett, installed on it, for this to work.  If you're distributing your app to users (via Cydia, or something like that), you can make sure that `PreferenceLoader` is automatically installed along with your app.  To do this, add this line to your app's `DEBIAN/control` file:

```bash
Depends: preferenceloader
```

`PreferenceLoader` is free, has been around for a while, and seems pretty stable, so it's not a bad dependency to have at all.  Most jailbreak users will likely already have it.

Comment: Thank you! I will start brainstorming. :-) Just as a FYI I am trying to do the following:
I have a custom SSH added C# (I think it's #) application that is under `/usr/libexec` that opens the device up as an airplay speaker. Its developer has the application load as a .plist daemon, but its annoying because its ALWAYS on and people start playing music to it. (I'm a student) Stories aside- I just want to make a toggle switch that when turned on starts up the application and when toggled off kills the process, thus closing the application.

Comment: @Sean, If it's iOS, I don't think it's a `C#` application.  Most likely Objective-C, or C++ or C.  For your problem, you'll need the **Preference Bundle Approach** from the documentation link I provided, since you'll want to execute code, not just set a flag.  So, the **Simple Approach** in that link won't suffice for you.  As to the rest of your problem, you'll need to use code to programmatically launch and kill an application.  I believe you can find answers to both here on Stack Overflow (i.e. those questions have already been asked and answered).

Comment: I will look into it, Ill comment back if I get any leads